# How to turn table of colums into rows in Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I would like to set up a live Excel query for our SQL database for product categories.
The way I will be able to extract, it will result in 27 columns - 
Supplier ID, Supplier Name, then Product Category 1-25 (in their own columns)

I'd like to have a second sheet in this workbook that takes the information and turns it into 3 columns that you can filter.
I'd like the columns to read Supplier ID, Supplier Name, then Product Category (only one column, with all non-blank results below).

It would look similar to the images attached, a separate one for Input and Output.

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

Let me know what you think - Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Query is the perfect tool for this, assuming you're using at least Excel 2010.

In 2016 go to Data on the ribbon then in the 'Ger & Transform Data' section on the left,  choose the Get Data button, choose Database then SQL Server Database. [Excel Menu options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlkjq.png)

Enter your SQL login details then you should get a Navigator window with all the available tables/view/stored procedures etc.

Select the table you want and click the Transform Data button. In the table display that loads up, select the Supplier ID and Supplier Name columns, then go up to Transform in the ribbon, then in the'Any Column' section (the 2nd grouping along) go to 'Unpivot Columns' and choose the 'Unpivot Other Columns' options. [PQ Menu options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6yYs.png)

You'll then have a Table with Supplier ID, Supplier Name, Attribute and Value columns. [After Unpivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/928cB.png)
Select the Attribute column and delete it, then double click on the Value column header and rename it to Product Category. [Final Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lahe3.png)

Go up to the Home ribbon, then Choose Close & Load, and then Close & Load To. Choose To load to a Table on a new sheet [Load Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVa5a.png)